# Search for duplicated rows in two numpy arrays with different length (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays with different length.

```
array([['A', 'B'],
       ['C', 'D'],
       ['E', 'F']])


array([['B', 'A'],
       ['C', 'E']])
```

What I want is to see is if they have common rows, BUT not consider the order. So in the above two arrays, 'A' 'B' and 'B' 'A' are duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution, where `a1` and `a2` are the first and second arrays, respectively:

```
a1[np.isin(a1, a2).all(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
array([['A', 'B']], dtype='<U1')
```